# Copy Postgres database from server to local via SSH?

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way to copy my production database to my local machine possibly over SSH?

I'd like to use it for testing and safe keeping.

What I need to know is where Postgres stores the database and what the best practice would be in this situation.

Comment: Use pg_backup and pg_restore/psql, that's the easiest option.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Thank you for your reply. Is there any risk when running these? It would be a darn shame if I lost this data

Comment: No, this is how you make a backup and restore it